# How can I make a parameter in JMeter constantly change?

Tags: jmeter

Please help. I need the CurrentUserId parameter to change. How can I do this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INqvR.png)

Maybe you can make this parameter customizable? So that you can make a variable for this parameter in the Post query? I don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace it with [`${__UUID}`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) function, it generates an [UUID v4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)) structure each time it's being called so if you put the function into the request body it will produce an unique value for each user for each iteration:

[image]

More information on [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)

Comment: Thank you so much! And I have one more question. The query generates a unique RegistrationId , I need this id to be passed to the next query. How can I do it?

Comment: https://ibb.co/NxyvnfZ
https://ibb.co/tqVSs0P

1. ApiSaveRegistration generates an id to pass to the next query, but the id is always unique, how do I make the id be passed to the next query?